# Filter on Spark dataframe is filtering out incorrect values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe raw_df that contains data read from a tsv file. I am trying to filter out data that has a combination of field6=true and field_event_list that contains 105.

raw_df:

```
field6:string
field_event_list:string
```

| field6 | field_event_list |
| --- | --- |
| false | 100,101,000,000 |
|  | 100,101,102,105 |
| false | 041,051,105 |
| true | 101,102,105,106 |

```
val filtered_df = raw_df.filter("field6!= 'true' AND field_event_list NOT LIKE '%105%'")
```

When above filter was applied, the first and third row are getting filtered out too, along with fourth row which actually matches the condition.

Please advise where my code is going wrong and how I can correct this.

**Expected result:**

| field6 | field_event_list |
| --- | --- |
| false | 100,101,000,000 |
|  | 100,101,102,105 |
| false | 041,051,105 |

Comment: The third: `not like '%105%'` rejects the record, because `041,051,105` contains `105`.

Comment: Thanks. But it field6 is not true. It shouldn't have got filtered out.

Comment: Then you are willing to set for condition: `"field6!= 'true' OR field_event_list NOT LIKE '%105%'"`, and not an `AND`. The filter will retain only a record if the whole condition is true. With `raw_df.filter("field6!= 'true' AND field_event_list NOT LIKE '%105%'")` it is of kind: `raw_df.filter("a AND b")`, and for the third record `b` is _false_.

Comment: I am looking to eliminate records that are true and containing 105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing what happens:

```scala
import sparkSession.implicits._

val raw_df = Seq(
  ("1","false","100,101,000,000"),
  ("2","","100,101,102,105"),
  ("3","false","041,051,105"),
  ("4","true","101,102,105,106")
  ).toDF("row","field6","field_event_list")

val filtered_df = raw_df.filter("field6!= 'true' AND field_event_list NOT LIKE '%105%'")

filtered_df.show()
```

yields:

```
+---+------+----------------+
|row|field6|field_event_list|
+---+------+----------------+
|  1| false| 100,101,000,000|
+---+------+----------------+
```

Based on updated question and comment you instead want:

```scala
val filtered_df = raw_df.filter("not(field6 = 'true' AND field_event_list LIKE '%105%')")
```

which yields:

```
+---+------+----------------+
|row|field6|field_event_list|
+---+------+----------------+
|  1| false| 100,101,000,000|
|  2|      | 100,101,102,105|
|  3| false|     041,051,105|
+---+------+----------------+
```

via chat it's been confirmed the data is from t/csv without schema nullability set, so the data is not an empty string ("" of size zero) but null.

extended sample data and response (with the above filter):

```scala
val raw_df = Seq(
    ("1","false","100,101,000,000"),
    ("2",null,"100,101,102,105"),
    ("3","false","041,051,105"),
    ("4","true","101,102,105,106"),
    ("5","true",null)
  ).toDF("row","field6","field_event_list")

val filtered_df = raw_df.filter("not(field6 <=> 'true' AND (field_event_list LIKE '%105%' and field_event_list is not null))")

filtered_df.show
```

would yield:

```
+---+------+----------------+
|row|field6|field_event_list|
+---+------+----------------+
|  1| false| 100,101,000,000|
|  2|  null| 100,101,102,105|
|  3| false|     041,051,105|
|  5|  true|            null|
+---+------+----------------+
```

'<=>' is a null safe equality check (null is false) and, as field_event_list may also be null, the other fields have to be checked for null.

Comment: Thanks, Chris ! I would want the final filtered df to contain only the 4th row which satisfies both true and 105 condition

Comment: @wazza - yw, updated to reflect the clarification - just use not to wrap the entire positive.  The other expression was filter "it shouldn't be true and it shouldn't have 105"

Comment: your comment and your clarified question are opposites.  remove the not if needed

Comment: "not" should be present.  I tried your solution. Blank rows are not getting filtered out

Comment: at this stage I'm left *very* confused about what you are asking for.  Your question indicates you only want row 4 - as such remove the not(, but above you say it should be present - this doesn't make sense to me.  If you want row 4 to remain after the filter - remove the wrapping "not", if you want rows 1-3 to remain after the filter - keep the "not"

Comment: Am terribly sorry. I have updated the expected result.

Comment: I tried this ```val filtered_df = raw_df.filter("not(field6 = 'true' AND field_event_list LIKE '%105%')")```. The blank values are getting filtered out along with row4. I would want blank values to remain

Comment: you'll need to update your question with a test row that covers what you are describing for anyone to help you further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255103/discussion-between-vvazza-and-chris).

Comment: Thank you, Chris. Your solution to add <=> worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Row without "field6"=true or "field_event_list" contains 105 can be left:

```
df.filter(
  coalesce($"field6", lit(false)) =!= true || !array_contains(split($"field_event_list", ","), "105")
)
```

Result:

```
+------+----------------+
|field6|field_event_list|
+------+----------------+
|false |100,101,000,000 |
|null  |100,101,102,105 |
|false |041,051,105     |
+------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to eliminate records that contains a combination of true and 105 event. Would your solution do that?

Comment: Also, am getting syntax error. ```coalesce($"field6", lit(false)) =!= true || !array_contains(split($"field_event_list", ","), "105")   SyntaxError: invalid syntax```